# Scrapy Xpath or CSS Selector for next chevron

Tags: python, css, xpath, scrapy

consider this url:  [boat listing](https://www.yachtworld.com/boats-for-sale/type-power/class-power-sport-fishing/?length=40-970)

I'm trying various selector methods to select the following tag for following the results to subsequent pages.

```html
<a rel="nofollow" class="icon-chevron-right " href="/boats-for-sale/type-power/class-power-sport-fishing/?length=40-970&amp;page=2"><span class="aria-fixes">2</span></a>
```

such that I select the right chevron (green highlight) to go to next page:
[image: paginator]

I've tried:

```
response.xpath("//a")  # I get tags but none of the chevron links
response.xpath('//a[@class = "icon-chevron-right "]')  #note the space after 'right'
response.xpath('//a[@rel = "nofollow"]')
LinkExtractor.extract_links(response) # does not find these links
```

have also tried relative or chained selectors. Can't seem to figure this one out and think its probably some tricky nested tags to foil people like me!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do this without finding and clicking on links.
You can get the text in the `<a>`-tagged element with `class="nav-next"` -- 88 -- then use that in a loop to navigate to pages 2 through 88 by changing the URL variable `page`, like `href="/boats-for-sale/type-power/class-power-sport-fishing/?page=N"`.

Comment: I can't even select that a tag using response.css("a.nav-next").  do you think these a tags are in some sort of script?   I don't even see it with something like response.xpath("//a/@class"). I get what  you are saying about the iterator.  But, can't really see a way to dtermine how many pages as I can't programatically read the 88 even though I clearly see it in embdedd in the a tags with dev tools.

Comment: I can read the pagination text via response.css("div.page-selector-text").get().  But, nothing in the chevron paginator.   I guess I could deteremine 88 by doing math on the "Viewing 1 - 15 of 1,316" text?

Comment: Yeah that seems simplest.

Comment: Maybe those tags get loaded by a script. The Scrapy docs give some diagnostic tooling and recommendations for how to identify and handle that: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html